# iPhone app Rejected with iPad 3 crash without log

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, ipad-3

That's what Apple said - the app got crashed for them against iPad 3, there was **no log produced**:

> The application crashed on the third generation iPad running iOS 5.1,
>   there were no crash logs produced.

What i did is that i re-signed exactly the  submitted .app, installed it on all the iPods, iPhones and iPads i had (unfortunately not iPad 3 - this case was tested against the simulator).

The icons property at info.plist looks good, all the resources are in the bundle. Confusing thing is that another app with the same code but another configuration is approved. Let me stress it out - both the configuration was tested with the submitted .app files.

Any clue, shared experience or workaround ?
The current plan is to make some slight changes and resubmit the rejected app.

Comment: only thing, I can think of is, if you use large hi-res images in your app, which you only load "if retina", you could get memory problems on iPad... Maybe you can try on someones iPad 3. Even though: The plan of a resubmit sounds good to me (if you're sure, it's a random problem and you don't annoy later users of your app ...)

Comment: @Kai the memory problem sound very reasonable, but the fact that this s an iPhone application and there was no problem running it on iPhone 4 makes it a low priority i believe.

Comment: @Kai ended up with the crash reports on my table pointing at two places near the retina loader procedure combined with a few macros, the method crashed is called only once during the class initialization to swizzle the methods if the image is available. That is only the second time the image-loader is used after the application launch, so it should not be a memory issue, but i've read the related SO question mentioning what you said is somehow possible with the low-memory warnings not being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple Tech Support was able to find the crash report, no matter how they did it and why they said there's no report in the first place.

The problem was that with the accessibility turned on the UINavigationBar class called `+(void)initialize` on the very application startup.